# Authors on Transhumanism ending humanity as we know it

Tags: reference-request, philosophy-of-technology

Humans are defined by plenty of animal instincts and impulses given by nature which affect our behaviour and existence in every way.

Tribalism, social rules, the need for a leader or an alpha male and violence to maintain order, territoriality, parental instincts such us the protection of the family or offspring, different roles according to cast and sex, the need for respect and to be accepted within the tribe, etc.  are some of the many features social animals have and humans as such are no exception to this. Plenty of those characteristics are blatantly shown everyday by nationalism, politics, sports, gangs (specially among youngsters), wars, commitment to marriage and family, etc. 
Some scholars believe that emotions are just part of the residual animal brain because plenty of animals experience basic emotions such us fear, anger, love, envy, sadness, etc. nevertheless they are a key in our every day behaviour and ambitions.

**Are there any remarkable authors who are in favour or against changing the human DNA to improve the human species?** Do we have a choice if we want to evolve as species and face future challenges? Aren’t we just chimps with nuclear weapons? If we did, could we still call ourselves humans? Isn’t this animal thing the very thing that makes us human? Shouldn’t we just embrace it and accept it instead of reject it by all means possible? Isn’t it true that when we think there is something wrong with the world it’s because there is something wrong with us? Would it be ethical to change the human species? Wouldn’t that be playing god? If good parents deserve the best for their kids, what’s wrong with providing your kids with  the best genes as possible? Who wouldn't like to have a genius mind in a perfect body? Aren’t we already altering nature to our benefit with technology? If so, what’s wrong with genetics, implants and Deep Brain Stimulation? Isn’t taking anti-depressants a form of transhumanism? What’s wrong with making the homo sapiens an obsolete species in impermanent universe if it is replaced with something “better”?
If eugenics were one the reasons for the Nazi Germany are we risking a new genocide with transhumanism? 
Should everybody have access to best advances in this field or it should be like education and health, just up to the economic means of the individual?  Isn’t this fear of transhumanism just an irrational fear of the unknown from our animal nature? Isn’t this just a generational fear produced because old human minds have trouble adapting to an ever-changing world just like fear of electricity, microwaves, nuclear power, the internet, computers or laud music being played by bizarre musicians?

Are there any recent authors which ponder on this topic?

> "I not only think that we will tamper with Mother Nature, I think
>   Mother wants us to." - Willard Gaylin (from movie Gattaca 1997)
>
> "Everyone takes the limits of his own vision for the limits of the
>   world" Arthur Schopenhauer
>
> "The future enters into us in order to transform itself in us long
>   before it happens". —Rainer Maria Rilke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transhumanist community that does advocate to change the DNA is called [Directed Evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_evolution_(transhumanism)).

[Julian Savulescu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Savulescu), [Gregory Stock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_Savulescu), [Riccardo Campa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccardo_Campa) are some authors on directed evolution.

Participant evolution is the term which advocates to improve the human race without turning to mutations or genetic modifications.

Some remarkable books on the matter are:

Transhumanism: The History of a Dangerous Idea  by David Livingstone

Transhumanism: A Grimoire of Alchemical Agendas by Joseph P. Farrell

[The Singularity Is Near](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Singularity_Is_Near) by Kay Kurzweil and excerpt can be read [here](http://stargate.inf.elte.hu/~seci/fun/Kurzweil,%20Ray%20-%20Singularity%20Is%20Near,%20The%20%28hardback%20ed%29%20%5Bv1.3%5D.pdf)

Transhumanism and Society: The Social Debate Over Human Enhancement by Stephen J. Lilley can be read [here](https://digitalcommons.sacredheart.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1006&context=sociol_fac)